# How to load set of images in a directory to a arraylist in python

Tags: python, arraylist

I'm new to the python, I want to load a set of images from a directory into an arraylist. I found a code which accesses to the directory and prints all image paths, but I want to load all images to an arraylist and open images using a `for` loop.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import os
from glob import glob
try:
    # PIL
    import Image
except ImportError:
    # Pillow
    from PIL import Image

def process_image(img_path):
    print "Processing image: %s" % img_path
    # Open the image
    img = Image.open(img_path)

    # Do your processing here
    print img.info

    # Not strictly necessary, but let's be explicit:
    # Close the image
    del img

images_dir = "/home/user/images"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # List all JPEG files in your directory
    images_list = glob(os.path.join(images_dir, "*.jpg"))

    for img_filename in images_list:
        img_path = os.path.join(images_dir, img_filename)
        process_image(img_path)
```

Comment: This code does exactly that! `images_list` is a list of file names, and you open each in a for loop and process it. **what is not sufficient for you here?** as it is, this question remains unclear. Since we're not a free code writing service, your best bet is going through a quick python tutorial and see if you can help yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `PIL` to process images and `glob` to find files you desire. Sample code:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
images = []
for filename in glob.glob('./images/*.gif'): # i.e. gif images
    im=Image.open(filename)
    images.append(im)
```

What you want to do with images after?

Comment: Beacuse I'm using this method to identify differences between images that are loaded to the array. Is there any better way than this